# Refresh application state running on background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiapplication

I have music player app, and when app goes background it show music control on locked screen, in my case currently playing on radio artist and song. I use following:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[PlayerManager sharedInstance] setupInfoForLockerScreen];
}

-(void)setupInfoForLockerScreen{

    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *infoCenter = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];
    NSString *songName = self.currentPlaylist.lastItem.track.song.length > 0 ? self.currentPlaylist.lastItem.track.song : @"";
    NSString *artistName = self.currentPlaylist.lastItem.track.artist.length > 0 ? self.currentPlaylist.lastItem.track.artist : @"";
    infoCenter.nowPlayingInfo = @{
                                  MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:     self.currentPlaylist.title,
                                  MPMediaItemPropertyArtist:    songName.length > 0 && artistName.length > 0 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", songName, artistName] : @"",
                                  MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: @(0)
                                  };
}
```

Problem is, when data changed and next song will be on radio, how do i tell my app to refresh itself?  `applicationWillResignActive` i guess called only once when app initially goes to background.

Answer (score 1):

The `MPMusicPlayerController` class has some methods and events to help with this.

First you need to tell your application to listen for the MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification event:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNowPlayingItemChangedEvent:) name:MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification object:self.myMusicPlayer];
```

This registers an event handler that gets called whenever the currently playing song changes.

Then call the `beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications` method on your MPMusicPlayerController to tell it to start sending you playback notifications.

```
[self.myMusicPlayer beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
```

You can control when you want to be notified and when you don't by calling `beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications` and `endGeneratingPlaybackNotifications` as needed.

Then create the event handler.  This is the method that will get called every time the MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification fires:

```
- (void)handleNowPlayingItemChangedEvent:(NSNotitication*)notification
{
    // Update the lock screen info here
}
```

Now whenever the currently playing song changes, your event handler will get called and you can update your now playing info.

Comment: Loughiln what if i did not use MPMusicPlayerController for playing music?